# Pick particular key-value pair as type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In typescript, I know I can create a type and using Pick to select particular key-value pair as type. but anyway I just select from object?

```
/**
select from type
type variableType = {option: string, value:string, url:string}
const variable: Pick<variableType, "option" | "value">[] = [
{
  option: 'a',
  value: 'a_v',
},
{
  option: 'b',
  value: 'b_v',
},
];

console.log(variable)
*/

maybe something like this?
const variable: Pick{option: string, value:string, url:string}[] = [
{
  option: 'a',
  value: 'a_v',
},
{
  option: 'b',
  value: 'b_v',
},
];
console.log(variable)
```

Comment: [are you looking to do something like this?](https://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2016/06/09/implementing-a-dictionary-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to use a literal type:

```
const variable: Pick<{option: string, value: string, url?: string}>[] = [
  {option: 'a', value: 'a_v'},
  {option: 'b', value: 'b_v'},
];
```